# WooCommerce - Create attributes based on text of the product

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, e-commerce

I have a CSV feed that is produced by a supplier, it has the neccessary information to populate product data but no attributes, meaning i cannot show a filter on the front end.

I'd like to know if it is possible to programatically create attributes based on rules i give of matching text.

For example, a snippet of product specification:

Chipset Manufacturer: Nvidia

Interface: PCI Express 3.0

Graphics Chipset: Nvidia GTX 1660 SUPER

Memory Size: 6GB

Memory Type: DDR6

Attributes in bold and values after:

**Chipset Manufacturer**: Nvidia

**Interface**: PCI Express 3.0

**Graphics Chipset**: Nvidia GTX 1660 SUPER

It may be really far fetched but i would love to know if there is a solution. .

Comment: It's possible but not by a short snippet, You'll have to lot of codes with logic and validation code.

Comment: Thanks, what language would you recommend? I am speaking with a JS dev at the moment but equally think this could be done via Python which if works, will output a new CSV feed for me to use with all the attribute values created in new columns if certain values can be validated.

Comment: It's up to you. I can give you a guide on how you can do it then you can do it in any possible programming languages you know. So first, you grab the product specification value from the relative column then you create an array from product specification by splitting its content by line break, now you have an array of lines from the texts.

Comment: now you can loop each line and match if the line starts with `Interface:` `Chipset Manufacturer:` and so on. keep the matched lines into a new array. now loop again and split by `:` and get the label and value. so now you have an array of arrays with labels and values. now you do any filter, validation, etc with the new array then at last append CSV columns and values based on the required import format.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful and has now put me on that line of process.